# $provide more than 1 value to test in a describe

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a Karma/Jasmine test for an Angular directive:

```
describe('placeholder directive', function() {

  // Bindable members
  var element;

  // Load module
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  // Mock service response
  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('PlaceholderSupportService', function() {
      return false;
    });
  }));

  // Bind references to global variables
  beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
    element = $compile('<input name="test" placeholder="Test" />')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
  }));

  // Check the correct HTML is rendered
  it('Renders placeholder as input value when placeholder is not supported', inject(function($timeout) {
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(element[0].value).toBe('Test');
  }));

});
```

It works as I want. However, I have forced the value of `PlaceholderSupportService()` to be `false`. I want to run a second test where I have this value as `true`. I can't seem to access `$provide` within an `it` statement, so how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could tell your `PlaceholderSupportService` to return a variable. And then, on your test block, you change the value of the variable. This should solve the problem. Here is the example:

```
describe('placeholder directive', function() {

  // Bindable members
  var element;
  var providerResult = false; //Here is the variable that you will change.

  // Load module
  beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

  // Mock service response
  beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
    $provide.value('PlaceholderSupportService', function() {
      return providerResult;
    });
  }));

  // Check the correct HTML is rendered
  it('Renders placeholder as input value when placeholder is not supported', inject(function($timeout) {
    element = $compile('<input name="test" placeholder="Test" />')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(element[0].value).toBe('Test');
  }));

  // Check the correct HTML is rendered
  it('Renders placeholder as input value when placeholder is supported', inject(function($timeout) {
    providerResult = true; //Here I will change the result of my PlaceholderSupportService
    element = $compile('<input name="test" placeholder="Test" />')($rootScope);
    $rootScope.$digest();
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(element[0].value).toBe('Test');
  }));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply re-structure your tests, to give yourself a `beforeEach` for each `it`. This code could probably be cleaned up a bit, but here's the idea.

```
describe('placeholder directive', function () {
  // Bindable members
  var element;

  describe('when placeholder is supported', function () {
    // Load module
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    // Mock service response
    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('PlaceholderSupportService', function() {
        return true;
      });
    }));

    // Bind references to global variables
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      element = $compile('<input name="test" placeholder="Test" />')($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$digest();
    }));

    // Check the correct HTML is rendered
    it('Renders placeholder as input value when placeholder is not supported', inject(function($timeout) {
      $timeout.flush();
      expect(element[0].value).toBe('Test');
    }));
  });

  describe('when placeholder is not supported', function () {
    // Load module
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    // Mock service response
    beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
      $provide.value('PlaceholderSupportService', function() {
        return false;
      });
    }));

    // Bind references to global variables
    beforeEach(inject(function($compile, $rootScope) {
      element = $compile('<input name="test" placeholder="Test" />')($rootScope);
      $rootScope.$digest();
    }));

    // Check the correct HTML is rendered
    it('Renders placeholder as input value when placeholder is not supported', inject(function($timeout) {
      $timeout.flush();
      expect(element[0].value).toBe('Test');
    }));
  });
});
```

Comment: Yeh I figured I could do it that way. But surely there's a way of doing this without duplicating 23 lines of code to change 1 word of it?!